# Send data from phone to phone over internet?

Tags: android

Is there any way to actually communicate between two android devices over internet without having to have any service between the two devices?

Like posting something to device2 from device1 without having to "middle-land" on any other server or whatever?

Another question: I tried to ping my phone over the internet (simply using the IP address), which didn't work, since it seems like my ISP shares the same WAN-IP for all the phones or at least a few of them. So is there any way to actually ping or send data to my specific phone just by using the IP or my Google account or something?

Comment: To ask is human, to search is divine.

Comment: I don't think you can send anything to a phone without having it connected to a server in the middle. IP addresses are a limited resource.

Comment: Ok, but well.. now Im gettig off-topic here.. but for instance the windows "pinging"..that has to some how transfer x-ammount of bytes to another machine/device.. or has this machine/device a minor server built in aswell for handling the request?

Comment: I don't beleive you can because there would have to be some central system set up to ensure the data gets to the correct place. The phones don't seem to have that capability. IP addresses are limited as Roman says.

Comment: Aaa to bad :(.. would be lovely not to have to "bounce" on another server/machine before sending/reciving data..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all the end user devices are behind a ISP's router, and many of them behind a lot devices in network hierarchy; Thus it is exceptionally rare that an end user device has public IP address.

Even if you want to run a public request listening server, you don't have to get public IP address for your device, rather a redirect is created at the router, which redirects certain requests to your device.

Having that said, you cannot communicate between two end devices using internet without a public server in-between them.

**So your possible solution could be**: (If you don't want to use an in-between server), you can send data using mms directly to mobile number.

Answer (score 2):

BitTorrent is P2P and works from behind common WAN IPs as well. You can implement something similar, but you will need to know the IP addresses of Devices A and B and the ports on which communication is to occur. These ISPs usually allow dynamic port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach static ip to one of devices. If you connect to Internet from your mobile service provider, providers usually dont supply static ip. You can get your ip dynamically and send to other device via sms.